# A word which means "someone who owns and or operates a space"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For my thesis I am investigating a way to analyse how crowds' engage with a space. A space could be a room, part of a room or outdoors. For example, a classroom, a library, a lecture theatre, a section of a museum.

I am looking for a word which would encapsulate people who own or operate these spaces.

"operator" and "land owner" are what come to my head but neither seem quite appropriate.

For example, "This will provide a means for X to optimise their spaces"

Comment: "Manager" may be !

Comment: *Owner* would fit for someone who owns a space, manager or supervisor could be used for those who operate it. You should give more details about the space...a piece of land, a bar, a school...? Different spaces would require different terms.

Comment: @jnd You named it, "operator." http://www.thefreedictionary.com/operator

Comment: How about "curator."

Comment: @Elian - a school operator?  A bar operator?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, "school operator" and "bar operator."

Comment: How about "proprietor"

Answer (score 2):

I would often use ***"[proprietor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proprietor)"*** in these circumstances. It seems to cover the notion of "the person with responsibility for, or authority over, these premises".

> - One who has legal title to something; an owner.
> - One who owns or owns and manages a business or other such establishment.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

[***Possessor***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/possessor) means:

A person who takes, occupies, or holds something without necessarily having ownership, or as distinguished from the owner. [Oxford Dictionary]

It is better to use *Owner and Possessor* at the same time.

They don't work for *classroom*, though.

Comment: That does not refer to ownership or operating/managing a place, something which PO is asking for.

Comment: @Josh61 That's why I suggested to use both Owner and Possessor at the same time. Operator or Manager doesn't imply ownership.

Comment: Yes but owner/possessor do not imply managing or operating a space.

Comment: @Josh61 Primarily opinion-based, but owner/possessor's chances of managing is is far higher than manager/operator's owning it or renting it. Even if a possessor sub-leases it again to somebody else, still the sub-leasee will be called a possessor. it covers a way more than you can imagine.

Comment: *Chances of managing* are opinion-based, not possession which has nothing to do with managing or operating a space.

Comment: @Josh61 Shall we stop here? You don't have to repeat what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ***possessor*** (one who owns or has control over a thing), ***property holder*** (exactly what it says, the holder of a property), or ***lessor*** (archaic) (one who leases something to another).

Answer (score 0):

Please, reconsider **operator**.

> : the owner or manager of a business [American Heritage®
>   Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/operator)
>
> : a person who manages a working or industrial establishment,
>   enterprise, or system [Random
>   House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/operator)
>
> *When the teacher operates the classroom in the typical mainstream
>   American way, the student's lack of reinforcement for his cultural
>   background, feeling of isolation, and lack of condidence is compounded.* [The Cultural Context of Classroom Practice in American
>   Schools](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5JHRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22operates+the+classroom%22&source=bl&ots=_Pv6IV7KQx&sig=tSaf2ebARH1qzO6QLyrQpypLK1g&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMImc3M4ITOyAIVSdgaCh0AkQIL#v=onepage&q=%22operates%20the%20classroom%22&f=false)
>
> *Too often the teacher defines himself and his co-workers as classroom operators only.* [Education & the New
>   Teacher](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=uXaQnghICggC&q=%22classroom+operators%22&dq=%22classroom+operators%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwjj592ghs7IAhVJVRoKHXCCA40)

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but there's a recognised term for this - 
[**Facility manager**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_management):

> Facility managers have to operate at two levels: strategic-tactical and operational.[2] In the former case, clients, customers and end-users need to be informed about the potential impact of their decisions on the provision of space, services, cost and business risk. In the latter, it is the role of a facility manager to ensure corporate and regulatory compliance plus the proper operation of all aspects of a building to create an optimal, safe and cost effective environment for the occupants to function.  (-- Wikipedia)

I know this doesn't specifically cover *ownership*, but bear in mind that the owner(s) would owe a duty of care to members of the public on their property. Therefore the business of 'facility management' is also their concern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term **occupier** in relation to the control of premises.

See, for example, the Wikipedia entry [Occupiers' liability in English law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupiers%27_liability_in_English_law), which lists tenants, owners and contractors under the term "occupier".

Answer (score 0):

Consider **managing agent**:

> A person who is invested with general power, involving the exercise of
>   judgment and discretion, as distinguished from an ordinary agent or
>   employee, who acts in an inferior capacity. and under the direction and
>   control of superior authority, both in regard to the extent of the
>   work and the manner of executing the same.  Source: [The law
>   dictionary](http://thelawdictionary.org/managing-agent/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use *occupant* because it can cover property, occupation, residence -- if not too broad for your use. In some instances you could switch to *occupier*. (OED)